# Create a view for a timesheet

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working on the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Consultant_Alloc ( 
    project_no      number(6),
    activity_no     number(4) NOT NULL,
    consultant_id   char(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    allocated_hours number(3) NOT NULL,
    hours_worked    number(3),
        -- SUM(Consultant_Alloc.allocated_hours)
        CONSTRAINT pk_project_activity_consultant PRIMARY KEY (project_no, activity_no, consultant_id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_consultant_id FOREIGN KEY (consultant_id) REFERENCES Consultant (consultant_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT fk_project_no_activity_no_budget FOREIGN KEY (project_no, activity_no, budget) REFERENCES Activity (project_no, activity_no, budget_hours)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

);


CREATE TABLE Activity (
    activity_no     number(4) NOT NULL,
    activity_name   varchar2(50),
    project_no      number(6) NOT NULL,
    allocated_hours number(3) CHECK (allocated_hours > 0),
    start_date      date, 
    end_date        date, 
    comp_date       date,

        CONSTRAINT pk_Activity_project_no_activity_no PRIMARY KEY (project_no, activity_no), -- Each activity must be unique
        CONSTRAINT fk_Activity_project FOREIGN KEY (project_no) REFERENCES Project (project_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT ck_dates CHECK (start_date >= end_date)
);
```

I need to create an oracle SQL view that details the number of hours worked on projects in the previous calender month. I am learning this for my business and would like some pointers on how I can do this as I have not a clue how to refer to all the projects in the previous calender month.

Thanks

```
CREATE VIEW time_sheet 
AS SELECT CA.consultant_id CONSULTANT, A.project_no PROJECT, A.activity_no ACTIVITY, CA.hours_worked HOURS
FROM  Consultant_Alloc CA, Activity A
WHERE -- in previous calendar month
GROUP BY CA.consultant_id
```

This is where i'm up to.

Comment: Or is there anywhere one can learn this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in determining whether a given date range overlaps with the range of `start_date` and `end_date`, right? (Or can `comp_date` be later?) I'm going to assume that the range `start_date` and `end_date` suffice; if you need `comp_date` you should be able to plug that in.

The formula for determining intersecting dates looks something like this:

```
(StartA <= EndB)  and  (EndA >= StartB)
```

In your case, `StartA` would be `start_date`, and `EndA` would be `end_date`, while `StartB` would be the first day of last month, and `EndB` would be the last day of last month. However, since Oracle dates include a time component, I'm going to say that `EndB` is the first day of the *current* month, and use `<` rather than `<=`.

So to get all activities that happened last month:

```
SELECT activity_no, activity_name, project_no, allocated_hours
  FROM Activity
 WHERE start_date < TRUNC(sysdate, 'MONTH')
   AND end_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'MONTH');
```

If I wanted to get the hours allocated to particular projects, I could then do the following:

```
SELECT project_no, SUM(allocated_hours)
  FROM Activity
 WHERE start_date < TRUNC(sysdate, 'MONTH')
   AND end_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'MONTH');
 GROUP BY project_no;
```

The difficulty here, though, is that there isn't a specific date for an activity; it looks like it can span across different months. That makes finding the hours allocated to a project *in a specific month* difficult if not impossible. All I can do is find the hours allocated to a given project where the activity's date range intersected with the range of days in that month. I think, for a given activity, you should have a **log** table for hours, e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE activity_log
( activity_no NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
, consultant_id CHAR(7) NOT NULL
, log_hours NUMBER(3) CHECK (log_hours> 0)
, log_dt DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL
);
```

Then, and I think only then, will you be able to get a report of hours worked on a project in a given month:

```
SELECT a.project_no, SUM(al.log_hours)
  FROM activity a INNER JOIN activity_log al
    ON a.activity_no = al.activity_no
 WHERE TRUNC(log_dt, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MONTH')
 GROUP BY a.project_no;
```

Such a table would also enable you to get a breakdown by consultant:

```
SELECT a.project_no, al.consultant_id, SUM(al.log_hours)
  FROM activity a INNER JOIN activity_log al
    ON a.activity_no = al.activity_no
 WHERE TRUNC(log_dt, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MONTH')
 GROUP BY a.project_no, al.consultant_id;
```

By the way, there is never any reason to use `CHAR` in Oracle over `VARCHAR2`, except perhaps to save keystrokes when creating a 1-character column (e.g., `CHAR(1)` instead of `VARCHAR2(1)`).

Comment: Very helpful David.. so an activity log is required?

Comment: I don't see any way around it ... for a time sheet you need to know who worked on what and when.